# Type hinting 'static' and 'self' in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PHPStorm, if I have a trait, I can type hint `$this` for the referencing class by adding this code to the beginning of the method:

```
/** @var MyMainClass $this */
```

The following does not enable the type hinting for vars of the form `static::$someVar` or `self::$someVar`:

```
/** @var MyMainClass $this|static|self */
```

Is there a way to do this with `static` or `self` in PHPStorm 8+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK that is not currently possible.

There are quite a few tickets in this regard -- how to type hint / treat `$this`, `static` or `self` in traits. To name a few:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16368
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17671

Watch those & related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.